# Where did node-awssum go?

Tags: node.js, github, amazon-web-services

I'm using a Node.js library called node-awssum which has been around for quite some time. But now it seems that the library has been taken down from Github. Does anyone know what happened to it and where I can find a replacement repository or a fork?

https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum

https://www.google.com/search?q=node+awssum

Comment: Fair question, I don't know why anyone would down vote it. awssum.io is full of links to the old repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `awssum`, `node-awssum` has been discontinued. See here :

1. Github [link](https://github.com/awssum/awssum)
2. npm [link](https://npmjs.org/package/awssum)

Comment: Btw: node-awssum only existed as a repo name, the package has always been named awssum and still is. It hasn't been discontinued, just moved and named correctly. :)

Comment: Thanks i knew about awssum before, just did not know about what happened to node-awssum.

Answer (score 4):

Note: I'm the author of AwsSum.

AwsSum now has a new plugin architecture and it also now has a GitHub organisation:

- https://github.com/awssum/awssum

The package currently on NPM is 1.0.0-alpha so if you want the old version, you should explicitly state that you want v0.12.2 in your package.json file.

In the new way of doing things, if you are only using S3, then you'd just put awssum-amazon-s3 in your package.json and awssum and awssum-amazon will be pulled in as peerDependencies.

Also note that the http://awssum.io/ site is still there but needs updating.

Finally, if you want to find plugins for AwsSum, do this to find what's available:

`$ npm search awssum-plugin`

Cheers,
Andy